# Maze generation algorithm design (Recursive Division)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, matrix, maze

I am trying to include a maze generation in my pathfinding visualization solution in order to generate mazes on what the current application can work on.

I found a very well structured website, there are bunch of maze generation algorithms, but I primarily focused on one: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm

My programming language knowledge is mostly C++ and the application that I have is built with that + SDL2.0.

My "grid" (2D matrix) is made of "cells/nodes" represented by box textures rendered on the window surface. Where each "cell" can be in different states - obstacle == it's a wall - white state == it's passage.

What I face as an issue is that my "passage" is sometimes blocked by the next wall generated at random - which leads to unsolvable maze.

The question is how to avoid a wall that is generated to not block a previously opened passage?

**CODE:**

```
void RecursiveDivision::divide(NodesMap* map, int x, int y, int width, int 

height, Orientation orientation, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    if (width < 2|| height < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    bool wallIsHorizontal = orientation == Orientation::Horizontal ? true : false;

    //Where the wall is
    int wX = x  + (wallIsHorizontal ? 0 : rand() % (width-1));
    int wY = y + (wallIsHorizontal ? rand() % (height-1): 0);
    //Where the passage is
    int pX = wX + (wallIsHorizontal ? (rand() % width) : 0);
    int pY = wY + (wallIsHorizontal ? 0 : (rand() % height));
    //How long is the wall
    int wallLenght = (wallIsHorizontal ? width : height);
    //On whitch axis will the wall be drawn
    int dX = wallIsHorizontal ? 1 : 0;
    int dY = wallIsHorizontal ? 0 : 1;
    //Draw the wall
    for (int i = 0; i < wallLenght; ++i)
    {
        if (wX != pX || wY != pY)
        {
            map->getNode(wX, wY)->hardChangeState(NodeState::OBSTACLE);
        }
        
        wX += dX;
        wY += dY;
    }

    //Render the current state
    map->render(renderer, nullptr);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    
    int nX = x; int nY = y;
    int w = wallIsHorizontal ? width : (wX - x);
    int h = wallIsHorizontal ? (wY - y ) : height;
    divide(map, nX, nY, w, h, chooseOrientation(w, h), renderer);

    nX = wallIsHorizontal ? x : (wX + 1);
    nY = wallIsHorizontal ? (wY + 1) : y;
    w = wallIsHorizontal ? width : (x + width - wX -1);
    h = wallIsHorizontal ? (y + height - wY-1 ) : height;
    divide(map, nX, nY, w, h, chooseOrientation(w, h),renderer);
}
```

**Example:**

[2 step from the start of algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0BNc.png)

**Example - "finished maze" on 20x20 tile map:**

[Finished algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtBI.png)

**Note**

The screenshots you see are from separate run of the program, so they differ. I hope you can get the point.

Comment: what is the question? How to generate randomly the maze such that there is a possible solution?

Comment: Yes, that is the question. How to avoid the blockage of the passages from the next wall that might be generated in such a way?

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63577921/edit) your question to clarify

Comment: "What I face as an issue is that my "passage" is sometimes blocked by the next wall generated at random - which leads to unsolvable maze." Can you please show an example of such an invalid maze that was produced by your code? Actually, can you show an example of succession of mazes built by your algorithm by adding walls?

Comment: Edited. Screenshots from the problem in general and finished algorithm execution added.

Comment: The reason [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm) doesn't work here is that the "walls" are not "cells" as in your case.
I doubt there's an elegant solution. You should consider different approaches to generate your maze. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Applications) may be of interest.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't do this: `bool wallIsHorizontal = orientation == Orientation::Horizontal ? true : false;`. Do this instead: `bool wallIsHorizontal = orientation == Orientation::Horizontal;`.

Comment: Benny K's comment explains why the algorithm doesn't work in your case. A simple fix would be to explicitly check that the created wall connects a wall to a wall (as opposed to connecting a door to a wall or a door to a door). If you have randomly chosen a coordinate x to draw a vertical wall from `(x, y0)` to `(x, y1)`, check that the two cells `(x, y0 - 1)` and `(x, y1 + 1)` are both walls (as opposed to empty cells, which would be doors). If one of those two cells is a door, then choose a different random `x`.

Comment: @Stef I really am in search of how to do it more elegantly as you said. What you have proposed might of work if I keep myself away from going to an index not in the matrix.

Comment: @Stef that wouldn't work in the case of a new wall parallel and neighbouring an old one. You'd have not only to check for gates on the extremities, but also for walls on the sides.

Comment: @Sho: I'm not sure how that could happen. If you already have vertical walls at x=13 and x=27, then presumably when splitting this section with a vertical wall, you will choose an x at random in [15, 25] and there is no need to add a check that the new wall isn't parallel to a neighbouring old wall? Unless the OP's current code chooses x at random in [14, 26], in which case this should be fixed as well.

Comment: @Stef, oh, right.. that was dumb of me. Considering OP's code though, the walls are placed at random in [14, 25] which would make my case possible. Might need to change it ^^ Edit: actually [14, 26], OP probably didn't thought of this problem

Comment: @Sho not dumb at all, especially if this is a bug present in the original code! And your answer with the suggestion to place walls at odd coordinates only is even better and avoids corridors with width 2 which can no longer be split into corridors of length 1.

Comment: @Stef that's a solution I came up with long ago ^^. It's actually pretty useful. In fact, if you draw one column out of two (the one with the walls) very thin, and same for the columns, you obtain the exact same representation as the thin one. So, there's no downside to it compared to the original, exept for the memory. On walls columns/rows, one cell out of two is guaranteed to be a wall. Same with paths columns/rows. So it takes 2 times the optimal memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the link you were inspired from, your walls take a space of one cell. The easiest way to avoid your problem would be that your walls can only be placed on one column/row out of two.

This is what would a maze with "thin walls" produce

[image: 3x3 thin maze]

And here's the equivalent with thick walls (what you're using)

[image: 5x5 thick maze]

As you can see, their grids don't have the same size, the first one is a 3x3, and the last is 5x5, without borders (edited since yours doesn't have borders).

- You need to have a grid with odd sides. If it's based of a thin maze, make the sides 2 * n - 1 bigger, with n the length of the side of the thin maze*
- Only place walls on odd numbered rows and colums (starting at index 0)
- Place opening in walls on even numbered rows and colums

```
To resume, you can place walls

o o o o o
o o o o o <- here
o o o o o
o o o o o <- here
o o o o o
  ^   ^
here  here
```

(*) 2n - 1 is without borders, else use 2n + 1

---

How to implement this in your code:

```
    const int truewidth = (width-1)/2;
    const int trueheight = (height-1)/2;
    //Where the wall is
    int wX = x  + (wallIsHorizontal ? 0 : 2 * (rand() % (truewidth)) + 1);
    int wY = y + (wallIsHorizontal ? 2 * (rand() % (trueheight)) + 1: 0);
    //Where the passage is
    int pX = wX + (wallIsHorizontal ? 2 * (rand() % (truewidth)) : 0);
    int pY = wY + (wallIsHorizontal ? 0 : 2 * (rand() % (trueheight)));
```

/!\ untested yet

Comment: sorry I am reading your answer for 10th time and I can't catch the solution you came up with. What do you mean by "your walls can only be placed on one column/row out of two" ? Thanks

Comment: @l000p I realised I'm trying too hard something useless, I'll just provide you with a modified version of your function, to solve your problem. Notice that your maze must have odd numbered sides, so 20x20 won't do. You can test it to know why ^^

Comment: Thanks for the support. Now the algorithm is working - [Maze Generated](https://imgur.com/a/Kx29MaP)

Comment: @l000p nice to know it worked! I wasn't so sure, as I just had a quick look at your code. I hope it didn't confuse you too much, and you got to understand how it solves your problem

Comment: @l000p also nice maze-solving algorithm :)